# Checkstyle in Maven project. Cannot fail the project in case of violations

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, checkstyle

I have a problems with Checkstyle plugin for java. I need to fail the whole multimodule project in case of any violations. In parent **pom.xml** I have the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ss.ita</groupId>
  <artifactId>jresume</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>JResume</name>

  <modules>
    <module>common</module>
    <module>persistence</module>
    <module>business</module>
    <module>logging</module>
    <module>web</module>
  </modules>
  <build>

      <plugins>
      <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.16</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <id>validate</id>
           <phase>validate</phase>
           <configuration>
             <configLocation>dev/checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
             <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
             <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
             <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
             <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
           </configuration>
           <goals>
             <goal>check</goal>
           </goals>
         </execution>
        </executions>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>

  </build>
</project>
```

My **checkstyle.xml** is placed in **dev** folder.

When I run my project with

```
mvn clean install
```

It prints the list of all violations. But It cannot fail the whole project. It prints SUCCESS for all modules.
I tried to use **failsOnError** and **failOnViolation** both. But It didn't work.[In plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html)  there are these requirements:

- Requires a Maven project to be executed.
- Requires dependency resolution of artifacts in scope: test.
- The goal is thread-safe and supports parallel builds.
- Binds by default to the lifecycle phase: verify.

Where I go wrong. Maybe I wrote my **pom.xml** in a wrong way. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/multi-module-config.html

Comment: @ShmulikKlein I tried to do my task with this tutorial. But result is the same

Comment: @Luchnik, do you still have this problem?

Comment: @MichalKordas No, I add "violationSeverity" property and now it works great. But still thanks for your concern

Answer (score 10):

Probably you forget

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <violationSeverity>warning</violationSeverity>
    ...
</configuration>
```

`violationSeverity`: The lowest severity level that is considered a violation. Valid values are "error", "warning" and "info".

The default value is `error`, which means `warning` will not make maven build fail.

see more details in:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/check-mojo.html#violationSeverity